# express handlebars template wont render partial

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

this problem has got me almost depressed..
not so long ago this whole app worked but recently (probably more than 3 months, perhaps 6) one of my routes refuses to render any handlebars template I pass it, including ones that are rendering successfully via other routes.

this is the offending route:

```
app.get('/ListContentItems', function (req, res, next) {

  try{
    getAuthToken().then(authToken =>{
      axios({
        method:"get",
        // url: "https://"+cmsEnvironment+"/content-repositories/"+respositoryId+"/content-items?page="+req.params.page+"&size="+req.params.size,
        url: "https://"+cmsEnvironment+"/content-repositories/"+respositoryId+"/content-items?page=0&size=2",
        headers:{
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + authToken
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          var contentGraph = response.data;
          var stringContent = JSON.stringify(response.data,null,'\t');
          console.log(stringContent);
          res.render("list-content-items",{
            static_path:'/static',
            theme:process.env.THEME || 'flatly',
            pageTitle : "List Content Items",
            pageDescription : "List Content Items",
            reqParams : req.query,
            contentGraph : contentGraph._embedded,
            stringContent : stringContent
          })
          // res.render('list-content-items',{static_path:'/static','pageTitle':'List Content Items - Success','contentGraph': contentGraph._embedded, 'stringContent' : stringContent, 'reqParams': req.query});
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          res.render('list-content-items',{'pageTitle':'List Content Items - Fail','reqParams': req.query, 'error':error});
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
    })

    }
  catch (e) {
    next(e)
  }


/* res.render('list-content-items',{title:"List Content Items",error:"figure out how to authorize so that i can list the content items and create links.."}) */

})
```

this is the template:

```
{{> header }}
```

```
{{#each contentGraph }}

  {{#each this}}
      {{log this}}
      {{this.id}}

      {{#each this}}
        
        {{#if (eq this._meta.schema 'http://www.coops.net/draping-config')}}
          <a href="/draping?id={{this.id}}&store=bccdemo">{{this.label}}</a><br />
        {{else if (eq this._meta.schema 'http://c1-qa.adis.ws/c/cmslabs/content-stack')}}
          <a href="/panels?id={{this.id}}&store=bccdemo">{{this.label}}</a><br />
        {{else}}
          <a href="/?id={{this.id}}&store=bccdemo">{{this.label}}</a><br />
        {{/if}}
        
      {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}

{{> footer }}
```

this is the log output:

```
{ id: '3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435',
  contentRepositoryId: '5c5c64adc9e77c0001d73a22',
  folderId: null,
  body:
   { _meta:
      { name: 'Image Block 2',
        schema: 'http://c1-qa.adis.ws/c/cmslabs/image-block' },
     image:
      { _meta: [Object],
        id: 'b7a1bced-e921-42ab-baef-b5aa43cd3701',
        name: 'Fashion_Womens_Collection_SSS',
        endpoint: 'bccdemo',
        defaultHost: 'i1.adis.ws' },
     editorial:
      { callToAction: [Object],
        useParentAsCtaHotspot: false,
        title: 'This coat is far too big',
        text: 'but it\'s trendy',
        overlayAlignment: 'Top Left',
        overlayTheme: 'Darken',
        alignCopyText: 'center' },
     aspectRatio: { w: 4, h: 3 } },
  version: 1,
  label: 'Image Block 2',
  status: 'ACTIVE',
  createdBy: '2f38a1a9-c76d-4f34-91fa-652d09b6eede',
  createdDate: '2020-08-11T13:45:50.420Z',
  lastModifiedBy: '2f38a1a9-c76d-4f34-91fa-652d09b6eede',
  lastModifiedDate: '2020-08-12T19:39:12.261Z',
  lastPublishedVersion: 1,
  lastPublishedDate: '2020-08-12T19:39:11.301Z',
  deliveryId: '3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435',
  _links:
   { self:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435' },
     'content-item':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435{?projection}',
        templated: true },
     publish:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/publish' },
     planned:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/planned{?epoch,time}',
        templated: true },
     update:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435' },
     'restore-version':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/restore' },
     'content-repository':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-repositories/5c5c64adc9e77c0001d73a22' },
     'content-item-version':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/versions{/version}',
        templated: true },
     'content-item-versions':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/versions{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'content-item-history':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/history{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     copy:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-repositories/{id}/content-items?sourceContentItemId=3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435',
        templated: true },
     unarchive:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/unarchive' },
     archive:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/archive' },
     'set-locale':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/locale' },
     'create-localizations':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/localize' },
     localizations:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/localizations{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'localization-jobs':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/localization-jobs/search/findByRootContentItem?id=3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435{&page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'edition-slot-associations':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/edition-slot-associations' },
     'edit-workflow':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435/workflow' },
     'content-item-with-children':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/search/findByIdWithChildren?id=3fae61b6-56ef-4c31-9c53-40f45131b435' } } }
{ id: '66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a',
  contentRepositoryId: '5c5c64adc9e77c0001d73a22',
  folderId: null,
  body:
   { _meta:
      { name: 'draping---sofa',
        schema: 'http://c1-qa.adis.ws/c/cmslabs/draping-demo' },
     SVG:
      { _meta: [Object],
        id: '1200180d-7332-4228-8e88-1919906e44b8',
        name: 'test_sofa',
        endpoint: 'bccdemo',
        defaultHost: 'i1.adis.ws' },
     Textures: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  version: 1,
  label: 'Draping - Sofa',
  status: 'ACTIVE',
  createdBy: '2f38a1a9-c76d-4f34-91fa-652d09b6eede',
  createdDate: '2019-03-12T23:20:41.925Z',
  lastModifiedBy: '2f38a1a9-c76d-4f34-91fa-652d09b6eede',
  lastModifiedDate: '2019-03-12T23:20:41.925Z',
  deliveryId: '66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a',
  _links:
   { self:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a' },
     'content-item':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a{?projection}',
        templated: true },
     publish:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/publish' },
     planned:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/planned{?epoch,time}',
        templated: true },
     update:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a' },
     'restore-version':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/restore' },
     'content-repository':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-repositories/5c5c64adc9e77c0001d73a22' },
     'content-item-version':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/versions{/version}',
        templated: true },
     'content-item-versions':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/versions{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'content-item-history':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/history{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     copy:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-repositories/{id}/content-items?sourceContentItemId=66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a',
        templated: true },
     unarchive:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/unarchive' },
     archive:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/archive' },
     'set-locale':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/locale' },
     'create-localizations':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/localize' },
     localizations:
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/localizations{?page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'localization-jobs':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/localization-jobs/search/findByRootContentItem?id=66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a{&page,size,sort}',
        templated: true },
     'edition-slot-associations':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/edition-slot-associations' },
     'edit-workflow':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a/workflow' },
     'content-item-with-children':
      { href:
         'https://api.amplience.net/v2/content/content-items/search/findByIdWithChildren?id=66436a40-eea3-414e-9036-98580220787a' } } }
```

this is visually what appears:
[image: Visual Output]

and the HTML output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Amplience Demo: List Content Items">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="DPR,Width,Viewport-Width">

    <title>Amplience Demo - List Content Items </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/custom.css"/>



  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/?id=&store=">
            <span class="d-lg-block d-none">Amplience - Content Simplified</span>
            <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Amplience</span>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link" href="/showJSON?id=&store=">ShowJSON</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/carousel?id=&store=">Carousel</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/panels?id=&store=">Panels</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/ListContentItems/5/1">List Content Items</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    
        <main role="main" class="container">





    </main><!-- /.container -->
        
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  </body>
</html>
```

I think it's quite clear that the body of the template simply isn't rendering.

but other more complex routes render as expected..

let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting a brand new project and pulling this one route in I had a moment of enlightenment - here's the answer for anybody who hits a similar problem:

I was using the express-handlebars package which defaulted to main.hbs as it's layout.

I'd written a bunch of conditionals in there (bit of a noob error on reflection) which was preventing the body ever rendering - must've been a bit of a fluke that only this route was broken.

Lesson: don't put any complicated logic in your main.hbs file if your using express-handlebars.